# How to retain asp.net formView insert mode and values if exception occurred?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

My form view is tied to object data source.

If the object data source insert method return false or error occurred, what should I do to retain the form view insert mode and values in `ObjectDataSourceMtInfo_Inserted`?

```
protected void ObjectDataSourceMtInfo_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            LogHandler.LogError(logger, e.Exception);
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;

            //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE OVER HERE
            //TO RETAIN FORM VIEW INSERT MODE AND VALUES?

            ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpSaveMtInfoFailed", "Error occurred while trying to save Mt Info./Header!");
        }
        else
        {
            if ((bool)e.ReturnValue)
            {
                ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpMtInfoSaved", "Mt Info./Header saved!");
            }
            else
            {
                //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE OVER HERE
                //TO RETAIN FORM VIEW INSERT MODE AND VALUES?

                ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpSaveMtInfoFailed", "Failed to save Mt Info./Header!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHandler.LogError(logger, ex);

        //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE OVER HERE
        //TO RETAIN FORM VIEW INSERT MODE AND VALUES?

        ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpFormViewMtInfo_ItemInserted", "Error occurred after saving Mt Info./Header!");
    }
}
```

I am aware of method below but I cannot use it because I cannot access `e.ReturnValue` from there.

```
protected void FormViewMtInfo_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    e.KeepInInsertMode = true;
}
```

### EDIT

I found out that `ObjectDataSourceMtInfo_Inserted` will happen before `FormViewMtInfo_ItemInserted`, so I changed my codes to below codes but it's still not working even though it execute `e.KeepInInsertMode = true;`.

```
protected void ObjectDataSourceMtInfo_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            LogHandler.LogError(logger, e.Exception);
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;

            //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE OVER HERE
            //TO RETAIN FORM VIEW INSERT MODE AND VALUES?
            ViewState["MtInfoSaveSuccessful"] = false;
            ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpSaveMtInfoFailed", "Error occurred while trying to save Mt Info./Header!");
        }
        else
        {
            if ((bool)e.ReturnValue)
            {
                ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpMtInfoSaved", "Mt Info./Header saved!");
                ViewState["MtInfoSaveSuccessful"] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE OVER HERE
                //TO RETAIN FORM VIEW INSERT MODE AND VALUES?

                ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpSaveMtInfoFailed", "Failed to save Mt Info./Header!");
                ViewState["MtInfoSaveSuccessful"] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHandler.LogError(logger, ex);

        //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE OVER HERE
        //TO RETAIN FORM VIEW INSERT MODE AND VALUES?
        ViewState["MtInfoSaveSuccessful"] = false;
        ShowJavaScriptMessage("popUpFormViewMtInfo_ItemInserted", "Error occurred after saving Mt Info./Header!");
    }
}

protected void FormViewMtInfo_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["MtInfoSaveSuccessful"] != null)
    {
        if (!(bool)ViewState["MtInfoSaveSuccessful"])
        {
            object _object = e.Values;
            e.KeepInInsertMode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I can throw exception in my insert method then catch it at `FormViewMtInfo_ItemInserted` to retain formView insert mode and values but that's not a correct way to do it because I shouldn't use exception to control my program flow.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?